# Is Assyria more beautiful than the tree of life?

Tags: genesis, ezekiel

Ezekiel 31

> 3 Consider Assyria, once a cedar in Lebanon,
> with beautiful branches overshadowing the forest;
> it towered on high,
> its top above the thick foliage.

Ezekiel compares Assyria to a cedar that is better than any tree in Eden.

> 8 The cedars in the garden of God could not rival it, nor could the junipers equal its boughs, nor could the plane trees compare with its branches-- no tree in the garden of God could match its beauty.

Genesis 2:9

> The LORD God made all kinds of trees grow out of the ground--trees that were pleasing to the eye and good for food. In the middle of the garden were the **tree of life** and the tree of the knowledge of good and evil.

Can it be that it is more beautiful than the tree of life? What does it mean?

Comment: It needs to be proven that 'the garden of God' is synonymous with 'the garden of Eden'.

Comment: The evidences have been shown in answer no. 53884.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not have an answer because we are comparing two trees of completely different natures, specifically:

- The tree of life in the garden of Eden was a LITERAL (real, actual) tree
- The tree to which Assyria is likened is a FIGURATIVE (non-literal, imaginative) tree.

The cedar of Lebanon to which Assyria is likened is called "beautiful and tall" simply to denote its political dominance at the time that Ezekiel wrote about (Eze 31:3, 8, etc), which was about 100 years before Ezekiel's time when Assyria was the dominant power in the middle east.

Thus, because the tree in the prophecy is figurative and the tree of life literal, an actual comparison is not possible because Ezekiel only used it as a rhetorical device, a figure of speech.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph refers to the Assyrian one of the many fallen angels, and Ezekiel addresses its beauty before the fall on day six with his Prince Satan (together with a third of his angels, Rev 12:4). This angel must have had to protect mankind (Adam and Eve) from falling angels at the time, hence they were in a garden assigned by God. So Ezekiel says it had to go down to the Pit because it had fallen also because of its pride against possibly Adam, since Adam (meaning :red earth) was not as glorious as the existing sons of God ( stars of heaven which mean the created angels in all their glory symbolically! eg. Job 1:6; Job 38:7).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).